# How to write $A\cup\emptyset\times A\cup\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How to write the cartesian product of this?

$$(A\cup\emptyset)\times (A\cup\emptyset)$$

Is it: $$A^2\cup\emptyset^2?$$

What does $\emptyset^n$ means?

Comment: It is $A \cup \emptyset = A$

Comment: Ok. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that $X\cup\varnothing=X$. Also, note that generally $(A\cup B)^2\neq A^2\cup B^2$, much like $(x+y)^2\neq x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Thanks. But that means $\{\varnothing, A\}=\{A\}$?

Comment: Why would that mean that?

Comment: Because I have a set $A$ and I can choose something either from $A$ or from $\varnothing$ (i.e., I choose nothing). So, I can choose from $A\cup\varnothing$. If we were two persons, me and my friend, we will choose from $A\cup\varnothing\times A\cup\varnothing$

Comment: (1) You can't choose from $\varnothing$. (2) I still don't see how that would imply that $\{\varnothing,A\}=\{A\}$ (in the case that $A\neq\varnothing$).

Comment: Ok. I think I am wrong how I modeled it. How to model a situation when someone can choose from a set $S$. He can either choose something from $S$ or stay idle and choose nothing?

Comment: I'm not quite clear as what you mean. But as much as I do understand, you might want to add another [new] element to the options which designates "choose nothing".